# Replace duplicate set of values with NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

If I had the following data:

```
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| email         | date_opened         | order_date          | order_id | product_name |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| abc@email.com | 2019-01-01 10:20:12 | 2019-01-03 09:21:43 | 1234     | xyz          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| abc@email.com | 2019-01-01 10:45:09 | 2019-01-03 09:21:43 | 1234     | xyz          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| def@email.com | 2019-02-11 08:13:46 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| def@email.com | 2019-02-11 08:15:20 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| def@email.com | 2019-02-11 08:24:43 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| def@email.com | 2019-02-12 00:39:21 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| ghi@email.com | 2018-08-09 01:24:54 | 2018-08-10 11:12:14 | 5678     | zyx          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| ghi@email.com | 2018-08-10 15:22:34 | 2018-08-10 11:12:14 | 5678     | zyx          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| ghi@email.com | 2018-08-10 00:12:14 | 2018-08-10 11:12:14 | 5678     | zyx          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| ...           | ...                 | ...                 | ...      | ...          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
```

How would I keep a single `order_date`, `order_id`, `product_name` against the earliest or minimum `date_opened` per `email`, and replace all other duplicate `order_date`, `order_id` and `product_names` as `NaN`s?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import psycopg2
import pyodbc

dwh_conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
dm_query = ...
dm = pd.read_sql(dm_query, dwh_conn, parse_dates='date_opened', index_col='email')

dfdev_conn = pyodbc.connect(...)
bkgs_query = ...
bkgs = pd.read_sql(bkgs_query, dfdev_conn, parse_dates='order_date', index_col='email')

dm_bkgs = pd.merge(dm, bkgs, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
dm_bkgs['diff_days'] = dm_bkgs['date_opened'] - dm_bkgs['order_date']
dm_bkgs['diff_days'] = dm_bkgs['diff_days']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')

dm_bkgs.index.name = 'email'
dm_bkgs.sort_values(by=['email','diff_days'], inplace=True)

dm_bkgs['order_date'] = np.where(dm_bkgs.duplicated('order_id'), np.NaN, dm_bkgs['order_id'])
dm_bkgs['product_name'] = np.where(dm_bkgs.duplicated('order_id'), np.NaN, dm_bkgs['order_id'])
dm_bkgs['diff_days'] = np.where(dm_bkgs.duplicated('order_id'), np.NaN, dm_bkgs['booking_id'])
dm_bkgs['order_id'] = np.where(dm_bkgs.duplicated('order_id'), np.NaN, dm_bkgs['order_id'])
```

My code somewhat works but I've noticed that the `dm` dataframe has 1433 rows and after the `merge` or join, the number of rows goes up to 1448. Not sure why that is as the `bkgs` dataframe alone has no duplicates...

Also feel as though the code is a bit messsy...

Expecting:

```
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| email         | date_opened         | order_date          | order_id | product_name |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| abc@email.com | 2019-01-01 10:20:12 | 2019-01-03 09:21:43 | 1234     | xyz          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| abc@email.com | 2019-01-01 10:45:09 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| def@email.com | 2019-02-11 08:13:46 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| def@email.com | 2019-02-11 08:15:20 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| def@email.com | 2019-02-11 08:24:43 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| def@email.com | 2019-02-12 00:39:21 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| ghi@email.com | 2018-08-09 01:24:54 | 2018-08-10 11:12:14 | 5678     | zyx          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| ghi@email.com | 2018-08-10 15:22:34 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| ghi@email.com | 2018-08-10 00:12:14 | NaN                 | NaN      | NaN          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| ...           | ...                 | ...                 | ...      | ...          |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve exactly. Could you add an example dataframe just like your data you already posted, but then with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
duplicated = dm_bkgs.duplicated('order_id')

dm_bkgs.loc[duplicated, ['order_date', 'order_id', 'product_name']] = np.NaN
```

It's essentially what you did, in generic form.