# Remove duplicate values across columns in pandas dataframe, without removing entire row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

I would like to drop all values which are duplicates across a subset of two or more columns, without removing the entire row.

Dataframe:

```
    A   B   C
0   foo g   A
1   foo g   G
2   yes y   B
3   bar y   B
```

Desired result:

```
    A   B   C
0   foo g   A
1   NaN NaN G
2   yes y   B
3   bar Nan NaN
```

I have tried the `drop_duplicates()` feature by grouping data into new data frames by columns and then re-appending them together, but this had its own issues.

I have also [tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467322/replace-duplicated-values-across-different-columns-in-pandas-with-0) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907315/replace-duplicate-values-across-columns-in-pandas), but still am stuck. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

(updated original question)

Answer (score 1):

Go through the codes. You will clearly see the difference between mask and where.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
df['A'] = ['foo','foo', 'yes','bar' ]
df['B'] = ['g','g', 'y', 'y']
df['C'] = ['A','G','B','B']
print(df)
"""
     A  B  C
0  foo  g  A
1  foo  g  G
2  yes  y  B
3  bar  y  B

"""

aa = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated)
print(aa)
"""
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True   True  False
2  False  False  False
3  False   True   True
"""
using_where = df.where(~aa)
print(using_where)
"""
    A    B    C
0  foo    g    A
1  NaN  NaN    G
2  yes    y    B
3  bar  NaN  NaN

"""
using_mask = df.mask(aa)
print(using_mask)

"""
     A    B    C
0  foo    g    A
1  NaN  NaN    G
2  yes    y    B
3  bar  NaN  NaN
"""
```

Comment: It's a great answer. Can I ask you what the flag `~` does in where condition?

Answer (score 0):

Without removing the entire rows, you can filter the duplicated value with NaN.

```
#df : your dataframe    
for c_name in df.columns:
      duplicated = df.duplicated(c_name)
      df.loc[duplicated, [c_name]] = np.NaN
    
    print(df)
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044159/replace-duplicate-set-of-values-with-nan).

Comment: thanks for your answer @HSL. In the above example i have wanted these removed as the duplicates occur across a subset of more than 1 column (2) but not 1 column alone. Do you know how to change your code to only replace duplicates with NaN if they occur over >2 columns? (I have updated my original question)

Comment: @btroppo I cannot understand what you say. What do you want to add to this? This table that you explains is 4 rows and 3 columns. You mean, check duplicates over more 2 columns, not 1? Because this code is checking just 1 column?

Comment: sorry, yes thats right, your code removes duplicates occuring in each column but if its possible i need duplicates removed if they occur over >2 columns? For example if i use your code for the dataframe i gave in the example but in col A row 0 a different string was present, say ”eg”, then the output dataframe would replace col B row 1 ”g” with NaN, but i dont want this

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
result = df.mask(df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated))
print(result)
>>>
     A    B    C
0  foo    g    A
1  NaN  NaN    G
2  yes    y    B
3  bar  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks im sorry i should have been a bit clearer and have updated original post, i want to keep data in certain columns when they occur as duplicates only in the one column. For example, in the above example i have wanted these removed as the duplicates occur across a subset of more than 1 column (2) but not one column alone? Does that make sense?