# How to merge pandas data frames without getting duplicate rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have 2 data frames, each with a common value in column C. I am using pd.merge to merge these data frames, but i dont want duplicate rows for each matching pair. This will be more clearly visualised below:

DF1

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
df['A'] = ['2_21','2_34']
df['B'] = ['X1','X2']
df['C'] = ['2','2']
print(df)

     A  B  C
0  2_21 X1 2
1  2_34 X2 2
```

DF2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['D','E','C'])
df2['D'] = ['2_27','2_35']
df2['E'] = ['Y1','Y2']
df2['C'] = ['2','2']
print(df)
     D  E  C        
0  2_27 Y1 2
1  2_35 Y2 2`
```

Unwanted output/dataframe:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='C')

    A   B  C  D    E
0  2_21 X1 2  2_27 Y1
1  2_21 X1 2  2_35 Y2
2  2_34 X2 2  2_27 Y1
3  2_34 X2 2  2_35 Y2
```

Desired output/dataframe

```
    A   B  C  D    E
0  2_21 X1 2  2_27 Y1
1  2_34 X2 2  2_35 Y2
```

I have tried filtering the unwanted output/data frame by removing duplicates which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75751595/remove-duplicate-values-across-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-without-removing-ent/75756326#75756326)but this doesnt work as i need to split the columns up into subcolumns and remove duplicates of the subcolumns, not individual cells (which didnt seem practical after attempting).

I also cant simply remove the unwanted rows in the unwanted dataframe as there are many randomly occurring rows that need manual removal.

The pandas docs on merge are [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) but it doesnt seem to allow this.

Does anyone know of a possible way to achieve this? I really appreciate your help in advance as ive been stuck on this for a while. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I you really want to merge all C's in df to all C's in df2 based on position, you need to create a join helper column like I did here with 'key':

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby('C').cumcount()).merge(df2.assign(key=df2.groupby('C').cumcount()))
```

Output:

```
      A   B  C  key     D   E
0  2_21  X1  2    0  2_27  Y1
1  2_34  X2  2    1  2_35  Y2
```

Then you can drop key column in results.

Of if you just want to concatenate the two dataframe side by side, then use `pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)`.